# Alsa: get audio from specific Input to specific Output stream for monitoring

Tags: linux, bash, audio, alsa, gstreamer

I'm currently trying to get Mic-in and Line-in monitored on Headphones port and Line-Out, respectively.

I tried with aplay / arecord even with alsamixer configuration; it doesn’t work.

How can I make this work?

Here is what `aplay -l and arecord -l` gives me:

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC662 rev1 Analog [ALC662 rev1 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC662 rev1 Digital [ALC662 rev1 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC662 rev1 Analog [ALC662 rev1 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC662 rev1 Alt Analog [ALC662 rev1 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

"line out" is not listed in aplay -l even though I have it in alsamixer

More details, output of :

cat /proc/asound/card*/codec#* :

https://pastebin.com/embed_js/X0Yir5mr

amixer :

https://pastebin.com/embed_js/r2B8X21V

Comment: `alsaloop -C hw:0,0 -P hw:1,0` (with your device ids, of course)? Are you sure you are not running Pulseaudio?

Comment: I added the list of devices in the question, and yes I already removed pulseaudio.

Comment: To clarify: You have two A/D converters (inputs) and a single D/A converter (output), so you can use *either* line out *or* headphones, unless you do mixer magic. `alsamixer` lists the *internal* codec mixers. So you can either (1) use an external application like `alsaloop` (which will loop one A/D to an D/A, or (2) try internal mixer magic. For the latter, put output of `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*` and `amixer -c0 contents` into a pastebin or similar, and edit question with link.

Comment: As you suggested, I added the commands output in the initial question

Comment: with JACK Audio Connection Kit you can simply make all connections you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's look at the codec. The codec description is a graph representation of the analog parts of the codec chip. Go through the description node by node, and make a picture as you do that (`connection` describes the input nodes), you are going to need it.

Your codec has actually 3 D/A converters, for Line Out, Speaker and Headphone (nodes 0x02, 0x03 and 0x04). However, ALSA in the default configuration can only drive one of these (for whatever reason). Each of the D/A `Audio Output`s is then fed to a mixer (nodes 0x0c, 0x0d and 0x0e). The other input of each of these mixers is a feedback mixer (node 0x0b). The feedback mixer in turn gets signals from the most of the pins, including the inputs, and it has ALSA mixer controls associated with it (`XXX Mic Playback Volume`, `XXX Mic Playback Switch`).

Note that there's no "line in" and simple "mic" inputs, so I assume your "line in" is one of the Mic's, and your "mic" is the other Mic.

So: Try turning on `Front Mic Playback Switch` and `Rear Mic Playback Switch` in `alsamixer`, set volumes for `Front Mic Playback Volume` and `Rear Mic Playback Volume`, and this should allow you to monitor both inputs *when playing back* to either Line-Out or the Headphones. The last part seems to be important, because if I interpret the values correctly, ALSA has not enabled one of the three 2-input mixers. According to your `amixer` output, you seem to already have tried that, but increase the volume to make sure you are not missing it.

If that doesn't work, make another pastebin copy of `/proc/asound/card*/codec\#*` with these settings in effect *and playback active*, so we can debug what goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the details, when I increase volume of Front and Rear Mic in alsamixer, I have the playback.

the problem is that I get mixed signals : 
( Rear Mic + Front Mic ) => Headphone , and the same for Line out 
( Rear Mic + Front Mic ) => Line out 

Is it possible to get distinct signal for each input/output  :
(1) Rear Mic => headphone
(2) Front Mic  => Line out 

I'm also working on solution using Jack detection (call a script to restore alsamixer configuration) to enable one of configuration, as monitoring is being done separately ...

Comment: Your codec has only one feedback mixer, so you can't make two distinct internal feedback loops. You could make one internal feedback loop, say Rear Mic -> Headphone, and then record the Front Mic audio, and play it back to Line Out with `alsaloop`. That means you can't play back anything else to the Headphone. Also, ALSA doesn't support this, you'd have to manipulate the codec directly with `hda-verb` from `alsa-tools`, and everytime ALSA access the codec, it will overwrite your settings.

Comment: thank you a lot, now I'm sure I can't do what I planned first. 

So I will try the alternative solution, jack detection + alsa restore configuration